# Differential Geometry/General Relativity Computer Algebra

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, computer-algebra

Hi,

could anybody recommend a CAS suited to DG/GR applications such as computation of connection coefficients or generating (and possibly solving) PDEs for, for example, an unknown metric of given curvature. Oh, and compatible Linux (I'm using Maple through wine but am having myriad problems. Also tried Maxima but I don't think it has a PDE solving tool.)

Thanks,

Mat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica has had GR stuff for decades (here is a random link:

http://wps.aw.com/aw_hartle_gravity_1/0,6533,512496-,00.html

but google search for Mathematica "general relativity" returns lots.

I don't understand your comment about Maple -- it certainly has a linux version.

Comment: I used this code from Hartle's book a lot. The only issue is that it's SLOW (although this is Mathematica's fault). I did first order perturbation of metrics and even then it took its time to figure out the various tensors. Also, Mathematica is pretty good at solving really ugly PDE's if you know how to give it the right kick. 

Comment: @Igor: I'm using my old windows version of Maple through Linux' `Wine' platform but it dies a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Although I don't have much experience using them (I keep telling myself I should learn one of them well) I know several such systems:

1. [MathTensor](http://smc.vnet.net/MathTensor.html)  for Mathematica
2. [GRTensor](http://grtensor.phy.queensu.ca/) for Maple (and a limited subset for Mathematica)
3. [Cadabra](http://cadabra.phi-sci.com/), not tied to any particular CAS system; although it uses [LiE](http://young.sp2mi.univ-poitiers.fr/~marc/LiE/)

Comment:  I think I'm in the same boat as you José. I use Maple and MatLab just unoften enough that I need to relearn everything every time. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend for Mathematica :
   http://www.xact.es/ 
 it seems to be the most advanced package for General Relativity.